# Save data in MongoDB subdocument with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, mongodb, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP I am trying to save data in a subdocument like this:

```
$mongo = $this->User->getDataSource();
$mongo->update($this->User, array(
    array(
        '_id' => $tweep['User']['_id'],
        'Services._id' => $tweep['User']['Services']['_id']
    ),
    array('Services.$.following' => $following)
));
```

But obviously I am doing something wrong as it doesn't work.

$following is an array that I would like to save under Services whith a specific id.

This is the datasource method:
https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.0/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php#L635

Comment: I'm not familiar with the php/cake syntax but that extra enclosing `array()` doesn't seem right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use updateAll() method instead of update().

or

use MongoDbCollection Object.
https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/wiki/How-to-get-MongoObject-or-MongoCollection-object

Comment: I found out to do it like this:
    $Users = $this->User->getMongoDb()->users;

Comment: That also worked for me, although it took me some time to figure out how to update. I wonder if there's a way to accomplish this the Cake way without the detour to the db object. Anyway, thanks a lot for the hint!